# Python and Dropbox: How to change SmartSync setting for locally created files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dropbox, dropbox-api, dropbox-sdk

I have a working Python script that generates and saves hi-res image files to a local Dropbox folder (synced through the Windows Dropbox app). Is there a way in Python to change the SmartSync setting for the newly created image from "Local" to "Online Only" so that I can save space on my local hard drive? I know I could use the Dropbox API v2 to just upload the file and then delete the temporary local files after, but I'm wondering if there is a way to directly change the file settings since it already gets saved to the synced Dropbox folder.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No, unfortunately Dropbox doesn't offer an API for managing Smart Sync settings like this, but I'll pass this along as a feature request.